# Easy proof that $\zeta(s)$ has zeros in $0 < \Re(s) <1$? (Existence, not location)

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

The Riemann Zeta function represented by the following series, valid for $\Re(s)>0$,

$$ \zeta(s)=\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s} $$

appears to have zeros along the line $\Re(s)=1/2$.

I know that proving the zeros all lie on that line is an open problem, however ...

**Question: Is it relatively simple to prove there are zeros in the domain $0<\Re(s)<1$?**

Comment: You need to use the functional equation to prove that

Comment: There are two standard proofs - one uses the xi function which has the non trivial zeroes of zeta and from which the von mangoldt formula for the number of zeroes follows in a standard way (using a theorem of littlewood that shows how one counts zeroes of holomorphic functions on rectangles and classical estimates of the gamma function) ; a faster but coarser proof uses $(s-1)\zeta$ which is entire and of order $1$ and maximal type (by estimates on the negative axis and the functional equation) so it has $cT\log T$ zeroes up to height $T$; since the trivial zeroes are $O(T)$ result follows

Comment: There is a formula in complex analysis, where the integral around a contour (of something related to $\zeta$) yields the number of zeros inside the contour.  Choosing the right contour, and integrating numerically, we can get the answer with error ${} < 1/2$, say, and therefore we know the exact number of zeros within.

Comment: Note that by the functional equation $\log |\zeta (-2n-1)|$ behaves like $\log (2n+1)!$ giving the easy but coarser way of showing that non trivial zeroes exist (they must be on the critical strip by the functional equation) and are $cT\log T$ up to height $T$ but von mangoldt is much more precise of course

Comment: I think the classical proof that there are about $T \log T$ zeros is pretty straightforward. This amounts to integrating around a box. Morally, the right side of the box is where $\zeta(s)$ converges, and so its size is easy to understand, the left side of the box can be written in terms of $\zeta(s)$ where it converges by the functional equation, and the two horizontal lines aren't big enough to matter. A slightly different proof might be to consider the Hardy $Z$ function and show that it's real valued and varying signs, and thus there are zeros on the $1/2$ line.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. I have spent a week trying to find easy to understand sources which explain these proof, but sadly I can't find anything suitable. I would appreciate it if anyone could link to suggested online notes/papers/articles. I have textbooks Apostol's IANT, Edwards RZ book, Stopple's too but none cover this.

Comment: @davidlowryduda - I understand the Cauchy residue idea of integrating around poles to give non-zero results.. but how does this apply to finding zeros? Do we integrate around $1/\zeta(s)$, and if so, can it be done using the $\eta(s)$ form of the function referenced in the original question?

Comment: This is covered in detail in sections 6.5--6.7 in Edwards book. Also in Section 14.1 of Montgomery and Vaughan in a more modern presentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach requires awareness of the functional equation and $\xi(s)$. Using the fact that $\xi(s)$ is an entire function of order one, one can deduce that if $\zeta(s)$ only has finitely many (or no) zeros in the critical strip then $|\log\xi(s)|\ll|s|$ as $|s|\to\infty$. However, using Stirling's approximation for Gamma function, one can see that $|\log\xi(s)|\gg|s|\log|s|$ when $|s|\to\infty$ in the positive real direction, reaching a contradiction.

The strength of the above approach is that not only does it show that $\zeta(s)$ has nontrivial zeros in $0<\Re(s)<1$ but also deduces that there are infinitely many of them.

For a more detailed account, you might want to have a look at Ram Murty's *Problems in Analytic Number Theory*. Hope this can address your concern!

Comment: Thanks - this has helped give me sufficient "strategy" about how to solve this, I will need to fill in the detail with self study.